# IOS toolbar not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, epub

i am new to ios programming. the problem i am having is i have set a toolbar in  my xib file but after running the app the toolbar dont show. i have added this below line both in viewDidLoad function and in delegate.m class but still toolbar not showing

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

here is my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *languages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    EPubViewController *epubView = [[EPubViewController alloc] init];
    [epubView loadEpub:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AtoZbook" ofType:@"epub"]]];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:epubView];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

EPubViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;


    loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(toolbar.frame.size.width/2 ,toolbar.frame.size.height/2);
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
    toolbar.alpha = 0.8;
    [self.toolbar addSubview:loadingIndicator];


    [webView setDelegate:self];

    UIScrollView* sv = nil;
    for (UIView* v in  webView.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
            sv = (UIScrollView*) v;
            sv.scrollEnabled = NO;
            sv.bounces = NO;
        }
    }
    currentTextSize = 100;

    //Webview
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* rightSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotoNextPage)] ;
    [rightSwipeRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* leftSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotoPrevPage)] ;
    [leftSwipeRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];


    [webView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeRecognizer];
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeRecognizer];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stratRolling)];
}
```

Comment: Where do you create this `UIToolbar`? You're accessing the VC's navigationController's toolbar. Is that the toolbar you meant to reference?

Comment: @Aaron i dont know. i just downloaded a library EPUB Reader. when i run the original library,first a table view comes and then on clicking of the row "EPUB" book opens.in that code toolbar appears fine. but as i want to load the book first in the start so i added some code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. which is lading the book successfully but not showing the toolbar

Comment: this answer actually solved my problem.here is the link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433040/ios-toolbar-is-not-appearing-on-top/22433821?noredirect=1#22433821

Answer (score 0):

A `UINavigationController` already contains a toolbar and you shouldn't need to create one yourself. If you added one under the "Simulated Metrics" setting this is only for show and doesn't actually add a toolbar to the view hierarchy.

Apart from having the statement `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;` you will also need to call `[self setToolbarItems:items]` in `viewDidLoad` for `EPubViewController`, where `items` is an `NSArray` containing `UIBarButtonItem`s.

If your idea is to initially only have a spinner in the toolbar you might want to look into the [`- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView%3a) constructor of `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: so what should i do ? i am getting compiler error on items

Answer (score -3):

The issue seems to be in your xib file. Please check if any auto resizing is set for toolbar?
Usually it should be selected on top and unselected on bottom. 
1) Go to the XIB.
2) Select toolbar[image: By Default Size inspector will show it like this]
3) Remove bottom vertical line and select top one.
[image: Correct Autoresizing option looks like this]

Hope this helps.

Comment: hidding toolbar has nothing to do with resizing, will you please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: Since you are not changing anything in your .m file, it should be visible. I assume it could be because of you xib setting. Which in case of a 4 inch simulator behaves differently than a 3.5 inch simulator. If it is correct as in the image above. Then some subview must be on top of it instead. Can you share the simulator screen and xib details?